# Tracking non-js hits via google tag manager

Tags: google-analytics, tags, google-tag-manager

I was reading [Simo's blog](https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/track-non-javascript-visits-google-analytics/) trying to identify a way to track non-js-enabled hits. A solution is given at the comments by a user with the moniker Duncan. He suggests creating a new custom js variable in Google Tag Manager:

```
function(){
return true;
}
```

Then the commentator suggests creating `a rule which matches on 'Does not equal: true'. I do not understand this bit. What does the commentator mean by 'a rule' and how do I realize this? Can somebody guide me.

Comment: Please read the documentation there is a supported way of achieving this.. search for the <noscript> tag

Comment: @Jelman thanks for downvoting my question. it would be better if you were to explain me the action to be taken.

Comment: i'm sorry my bad I didn't quite read your question fully, but it's a bit strangely stated

Comment: i can only upvote again after an edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a custom JS variable
   [image]
2. Create a new trigger, for example a pageview trigger, and in the conditions options do the following
   [image]
3. Now this trigger should only fire when there's a pageview in a browser that does not have Javascript on because then the function will never execute and it will never be true.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Javascript variable. If javascript is disabled it will not be executed. Therefore the value is never equal to true in a browser that does not execute javascript.

Since there is a supported way of passing in variables (i.e. appending them to the url of the noscript iframe) I don't think you need to use such a workaround, funny as it might be.

Comment: `there is a supported way of passing in variables (i.e. appending them to the url of the noscript iframe)`. Could you please elaborate? I am new in Google Tag Manager and Google Analytics.

Comment: `https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/devguide#adding-data-layer-variables-for-devices-without-javascript-support` - I found this. Is this the supported way you were referring to?